# is it possible to make software using python only?

Tags: python, machine-learning, software-design

I want to make a small .exe file that will work in any PCs , is it possible to make and if yes then what is the procedure ?

Comment: Have a look at the `pyinstaller` package.

Comment: You can use pyinstaller library to create .exe file from python code. I'd recommend using a new env before doing it.

Comment: I have made one using pyinstaller but it made a number of files of around 800 MB for just 50 lines of codes in python.

Comment: I want to make a file of aroung 50MB at most

Comment: Python isn't the ideal language with which to create small executables. Better (albeit harder) to use something like C or C++.

Comment: "is it possible to make software using python only" um, yes? Python is a programming langauge, to program *software*. what do you mean by "software" exactly?

Comment: @shivamkumar0611 is my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe

[image]

It's an open source project called auto-py-to-exe. It's a GUI with PyInstaller internally, making more confortable alternative.  It can also output a standalone file in contrast to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote a terrible question, I will write a terrible answer:

Yes, you can make .exe files in python. You need a package called "psutil" which can convert your .py files into .exe files AND convert them into executables for other operating systems as well. A .exe file only works on Windows, so some PC running a Linux Distro won't be able to run it.

Edit: pyinstaller is also useful when you want to just make a .exe